# PHP eclipse not seeing autocomplete for javascript

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse

I have recently taken the dive into eclipse environment from dreamweaver so I can have more control over my php with debugging etc.  I decided to use Pulse to manage my extensions and start with a fresh Eclipse classic version and tailor it to my needs (I felt aptana was too bloated).  The only problem I see is I create a new PHP projects and enable javascript and everything works fine but I am seeing PHP autocomplete to help with functions but it is not working for javascript syntax or html for autocomplete.  Also I am curious about how jQuery will work in this environment also.

Also any other suggestions to use eclipse for web development would be awesome also.  here is a listen of extensions I have installed:

- Drupal for eclipse pdt
- PHP development tools
- Javascript development tools
- Eclipse Web developer Tools

Comment: LoL - that's probably a feature they made in order to prevent you from writing spaghetti code...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense you either did not read or did not understand what I was asking.  Its a simple thing many editors have when you are writing javascript you autocomplete with javascript functions.  When writing in a php tag you autocomplete with php functions.  I don't think that is spaghetti code at all

Comment: I totally got what you asked, combine HTML/JS with PHP and you get a mix of client-side and server-side code which is called spaghetti  ;)

Comment: Eclipse is bloated. Aptana just lights the match.